# How to replace a string starting with a letter in Java

Tags: java

I want to create a method that print out the elements in ArrayList. 
If the String start with a, e, i, o or u, instead of printing the String, it should print Buzz.

I am trying this way. But it isn't work.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("Harry");
    names.add("Kathy");

ArrayList<String> replaceArray = new ArrayList<>();

    String buzzReplace[] ={"a","e","i","o","u"};



    for(String value:names)
    {
        if(value.startsWith(buzzReplace))
        {
            replaceArray = names.replaceAll(value,"Buzz");
        }

        System.out.println(replaceArray.get(value));
    }
```

I found a simply solution :

```
for (String name: names) {
 for (String vowel: buzzReplace) {
       if (name.startsWith(vowel)) {
          name = "buzz";
          break; 
       }
  }
  System.out.println(name);
```

}

Comment: Can you please provide sample I/O?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(value.startsWith(buzzReplace))
```

If you think about the types involved here, clearly a string cannot start with an array of strings. A string can possibly start with another string.

So you need to iterate over the contents of your `buzzReplace` list:

```
for(String name : names)
{
    for (String vowel : buzzReplace)
    {
        if (name.startsWith(vowel))
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Your use of `replaceAll` is also incorrect and does not match the method signature. I'll leave it up to you to fix that element of your code. (a hint: you do not need to modify the contents of the list)

Comment: i am trying  name = name.replaceAll(vowel, "buzz"); .But this only replace the first letter.

Comment: i got it. thank you :D .. just this:   name = "buzz";

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 you could do something like this:

```
public List<String> buzz(List<String> names) {
    List<Character> buzzChars = Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
    return names.stream()
            .map(name -> buzzChars.contains(name.toLowerCase().charAt(0)) ? "Buzz" : name)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if(value.startsWith(buzzReplace))
```

try

```
String[] buzzReplace ={"a","e","i","o","u"};
if (Arrays.asList(buzzRepalce).contains(value.subString(0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer idea is like Jamesp's answer but as your code has some bugs and maybe you face them in next step, I send whole method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("Harry");
    names.add("Kathy");
    names.add("aathy");


    ArrayList<String> replaceArray = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] buzzReplace ={"a","e","i","o","u"};

    for(String value:names)
    {
        if(Arrays.asList(buzzReplace).contains(value.substring(0,1)))
        {
            replaceArray.add("Buzz");
        }
        else replaceArray.add(value);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(replaceArray.toArray()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write some method that does the task. let say. `getReplacedList(List<String> names)`

Now get the replaced array from that method.

```
private static List<String> getReplacedList(List<String> names) {
    ArrayList<String> replaceArray = new ArrayList<>();
    String buzzReplace = "aeiou";

    names.stream().forEach(name ->{
        //user to lower case if you want to ignore case.
        if (buzzReplace.contains(name.toLowerCase().charAt(0)+"")) {
            //do some thing like 
            replaceArray.add("Buzz");
        } else {
            replaceArray.add(name);
        }

    });

    return replaceArray;
}
```

Now pass your original list to this method to get the replaced list.

Your solution look like.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("Harry");
    names.add("Kathy");     

    List<String> replaceArray = new ArrayList<>();
    replaceArray = getReplacedList(names);

    //do some thing with replace array.
    System.out.println(replaceArray.toString());
}

private static List<String> getReplacedList(List<String> names) {
    ArrayList<String> replaceArray = new ArrayList<>();
    String buzzReplace = "aeiou";

    names.stream().forEach(name ->{
        //user to lower case if you want to ignore case.
        if (buzzReplace.contains(name.toLowerCase().charAt(0)+"")) {
            //do some thing like 
            replaceArray.add("Buzz");
        } else {
            replaceArray.add(name);
        }

    });

    return replaceArray;
}
```